# How to remove a message subscription when a page is destroyed

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a page that subscribes to a message. When the page is in memory but not visible, I still want it to receive messages. However, if the UI is rebuilt, the page will be destroyed - and this can happen also whilst the page is not visible. When the page is destroyed, how can I unsubscribe from the message?

Is this even necessary? Will the page be unsubscribed when or if it's garbage collected?

Checkinging in the debugger, it looks as though pages are gradually removed and the subscription goes with them. If I open several pages of the same type, then the number of subscribers responding gradually reduces. The count will go as high as ten or eleven and then drop down to three or four.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Xamarin.Forms `MessagingCenter` and subscribing on the page itself when the page is garbage collected it will no longer be subscribed. However, it can be a while before garbage collection actually runs so if you have multiple instances of a page still alive they will still be subscribed to your message.

If you're okay with the possibility of multiple pages receiving messages they will eventually be gc'ed and won't cause a memory leak because you didn't unsubscribe, if that's what you're worried about.

If you do want to ensure only single instances of pages that are still in the `NavigationStack` are subscribed to a message I would `override OnParentSet` and unsubscribe there.

```
protected override void OnParentSet()
{
    base.OnParentSet();

    if (Parent == null)
    {
        MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<MainPage>(this, "message");
    }
}
```